# Load a custom google map to android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm new to android development.

I need to load a custom google-map someone made in google maps (a map with marks and information).
My question is how to load this map on a android app (and not just creating a new map and manually adding all the markers and information -- because than each time client wants to change something in the map he will need to change it in 2 places).

I know i can just make a webview but than i can't access the location and focus on users location -- is there any other way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the location of your indicated region and add the markers manually if there isn't place to mark.

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker